# Problems with IE and Edge, probably scroll smoothing

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, smooth-scrolling, microsoft-edge

I have fixed header that animates up (by the height of header) if scrolled down and reappears when scrolled up.

I had header jumping issues before with IE and I used this:

```
//IE jumping fixed elements fix
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) { // if IE
    $('body').on("mousewheel", function () {
        //Remove default behavior
        event.preventDefault(); 

        //Scroll without smoothing
        var wheelDelta = event.wheelDelta;
        var currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
        window.scrollTo(0, currentScrollPosition - wheelDelta);
    });
}
```

It shows JS error that `Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDefault'` with every scroll but it somehow works.

But now with new Edge, even this doesn't work (I tried `/Edge\/12./`). Everything works nicely with Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to call `.preventDefault` off of `event`, but `event` isn't in your handler's list of arguments. As such, `event` is either defined outside of this scope, or *undefined*. Either way, it's not what you're expecting.

One other suggestion (in particular for older versions of IE and older hardware) would be to throttle this method so that it's not running dozens of times each second.

Microsoft Edge should function like Chrome and Firefox. If it's not, please direct me to a resource that shows the issue and I'll gladly file a bug for the team to evaluate.

Comment: That's the weird part, this code works in IE (10-11 at least) like it is, it **doesn't** work if event is added to function parentheses. Im pretty sure I throttle it with other plugin because error is only thrown like 8 times per long scroll.

Comment: Can you link to an online resource that shows the broken behavior? With the current user-agent match, this logic wouldn't run in IE 10 or 11, or Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Sure, give me a sec, I'll disable "under construction". Here's  [link](https://www.prii.eu). Don't mind the mess, it's under construction.

Comment: Did you see the problem? I could try but what usually happens with that kind of problems is that I couldn't reproduce the problematic behaviour.

Comment: If you aren't able to repro the issue in minimal form, the error is likely elsewhere. I do see the jumpy behavior. Having a minimal repro will be best for debugging, as well as making sure others here will be able to see the issue long after it's resolved on your domain.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a shot. But I can't imagine what could cause this because I commented out every line of code that could alter header, also toggled 99% of CSS rules.

Comment: We'll figure it out :)

Comment: I figured it out and again: it only occured in IE and Edge. Problem was that element with `position: fixed` was inside element with  `position: fixed`. I changed my HTML layout and it works now - no more jumping. Why I did it? I wrote this code long time ago but I remember that child element didn't inherit `position: fixed` for some reason. Im not sure if that's bad practise or not but if it's commonly used practise, I suggest you to look into it.

Comment: @Solo I'm happy to hear the issue is resolved. If Microsoft Edge treats this positioning/layout scenario differently than Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, I would like to file an interop bug for our team to investigate. Can you help me by creating a small piece of HTML/CSS that shows the disparity between Edge and other browsers?

Comment: That's going to be a problem Im afraid, I tried it several times yesterday but it didn't work out. There must be something else thrown to the mix in order to get the bug "work".

Comment: @Solo At the very least, I do appreciate your patience and willingness to be flexible - the sign of a true professional :)

Comment: Haha, a year into this. Im afraid I've got a long way to go. Still, I think I know few things. I'll let you know in comments if I happen to stumble on the other part of this mix which caused the bug.. If it happens. Thank you for your time.